# What's a better way to use a query to re-order entries in a queue

Tags: oracle

Oracle 19

I have a process where tickets are ordered in a queue, various processes can add and remove items from the queue, and I don't totally trust the code writing to the queue to not duplicate ranking, so I need a way to regularly re-order the queue. I have a working query, but just wonder if there is a better way to do it.

The important parts of the table:

`ticket_id  number(10)`         the PK for the table
`queue_rank number(3)`          the rank of the ticket, or null if not in the queue
`ticket_state varchar2(32)`     the current state of the entry, 'Queued' is the only state where queue_rank matters
`create_date date`              duh

The query I am running is:

```
UPDATE  ticket_detail TD
   SET  TD.queue_rank = (SELECT  TD2.newrank
                                FROM  ( SELECT ticket_id,
                                            row_number() OVER (ORDER BY queue_rank, create_date) AS newrank
                                        FROM ticket_detail
                                        WHERE ticket_state = 'Queued'
                                        ) TD2
                                WHERE  TD.ticket_id = TD2.ticket_id
                            )
 WHERE  TD.ticket_state = 'Queued'
    OR  TD.queue_rank IS NOT NULL
```

My query seems to do what I need it to do and works in all the test cases I have come up with so far.

Is this the best way to do this?

The code is an small internal use app. The table will likely only have a couple hundred entries per year with maybe 30-40 in the queue at any one time. I plan to run the re-order query only after an action that might affect the queue order in some way.

The nested subqueries bother me, and the query is doing two full scans for a small query. It is still more than fast enough for my use case, hoping to learn better ways to solve the problem.

Comment: Have you considered using advanced queuing?  https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adque/#Oracle%C2%AE-Database
It's deigned exactly for this .. push items into a "queue", you define the rules/etc for them, and when a user requests to "pop" an item, they just get the next item .., 
Otherwise, I wouldn't recommend doing a reorder. I'd recommend using a VIEW built ontop of your table, with that  "row_number() over (order by <blah>)" that you need .. expose the view ONLY to users .. and make them update/grab an item via a package .. and you're kinda rebuilding queues.

Comment: I'll have to investigate advanced queueing (had forgotten it existed). It might be overpowered for what I need here, but it would solve the messaging system I need to add to this app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can correlate using the `ROWID` pseudo-column, which is effectively a pointer to a row (rather than using the primary key):

```sql
UPDATE  ticket_detail TD
SET  queue_rank = ( SELECT newrank
                    FROM   (
                      SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY queue_rank, create_date) AS newrank
                      FROM   ticket_detail
                      WHERE  ticket_state = 'Queued'
                    ) TD2
                    WHERE  TD.ROWID = TD2.ROWID
                  )
WHERE  ticket_state = 'Queued'
OR     queue_rank IS NOT NULL
```

---

You could also use a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO ticket_detail dst
USING (
  SELECT CASE ticket_state
         WHEN 'Queued'
         THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY ticket_state
                ORDER BY queue_rank, create_date
              )
         ELSE NULL
         END AS newrank
  FROM   ticket_detail
  WHERE  ticket_state = 'Queued'
  OR     queue_rank IS NOT NULL
) src
ON (src.ROWID = dst.ROWID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET queue_rank = newrank
  -- WHERE dst.queue_rank != src.new_rank
  -- OR    (dst.queue_rank IS NULL AND src.new_rank IS NOT NULL)
  -- OR    (dst.queue_rank IS NOT NULL AND src.new_rank IS NULL)
```

You could, optionally, add a `WHERE` filter to the `MERGE` statement to only update the row when there is a change.

Comment: the where clause would need to cater for null `queue_rank`s as well, assuming a row could be queued without a queue_rank.

Comment: I like the merge solution. It is still doing full table scans, but the answer seems cleaner to me - at least fewer sub queries and easier to comment.